# apache2 wrong Main Documentroot

Tags: apache-2.4

I have a apache2 running, setup with two vhost.

One site is working fine. But the other one is redirected to a wrong directory.
The configuration files are exactly the same except the server names and aliases and the document root of curse.

So I looked with `apachectl -S` and there is an additional entry
`Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"`
I found no .conf file where this directory is set.

How can I change it to point to the directory of the second vhost which is showing this wrong directory?

My vhost config(as in question):

```
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAlias mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1/privkey.pem

</VirtualHost>


</IfModule>
```

The other one is equal only with other directorys and alias.

Comment: It must be in some config file. Check the `Include` and `Include Optional` parameter in `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` then check all config files in those folders.

Comment: i have checked all files under /etc/apache2 and all subdir... there are no config files included in other directorys. Thats why I'm asking how to set the "Main DocumentRoot"  (not the "DocumentRoot"-Directive this is set correctly in the vhosts). There must be a way to set this. i've allready tried to set the DocumentRoot in 000-default.conf  file with `<VirtualHost _default_:80>` but this is not changing the entry "Main DocumentRoot"...

Comment: `grep -R "DocumentRoot" /etc/apache2`

Comment: shows only my two DocumentRoots which are set in the vhosts ( all twice since they are under /sites-available and linked in /sites-enabled ) .. even when i use `grep -R "DocumentRoot" / ` only this two directorys are shown..

Comment: Can you post your config please?

Comment: i've added it in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58105/discussion-between-mzhaase-and-chwzr).

Comment: So ho did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, "Main DocumentRoot" is the DocumentRoot defined outside of any VirtualHost block and "/var/www/html" is the factory default.

This newer question contains a good answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56812397/6918262

Answer (score 0):

As the name already suggests, it is the default DocumentRoot value for virtual hosts when they themselves don’t specify one. So if a request matches a virtual host block which lacks a DocumentRoot directive to fulfil the request, Apache will use the default or main document root to serve the request.

Apache default document root specified in two places,

1. Compile-time or Runtime options of httpd.
2. The main server config which is the configuration specified outside the
   virtual host blocks. Any virtual host configuration basically picks up
   default values from the main server config.

Note: The document root value specified in the main server config will override the one inherited from compile-time or runtime option.

Please refer this link for more information:

[https://codingshower.com/apache-find-default-or-main-documentroot/#:~:text=The%20default%20or%20main%20document%20root%20acts%20as%20the%20default,and%20the%20main%20server%20config](https://codingshower.com/apache-find-default-or-main-documentroot/#:%7E:text=The%20default%20or%20main%20document%20root%20acts%20as%20the%20default,and%20the%20main%20server%20config)